# How to move one object from another class with keyboard in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, opengl-1.x

How can I to move from keyboard my Sphere in OpenGL if my Sphere is one class?

main:

```
#include "glos.h"
#include <gl.h>
#include <glu.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <glaux.h>
#include <math.h>  
#include"Sphere.cpp"
using namespace std;

void myinit(void);
void CALLBACK myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h);
void CALLBACK display(void);

Sphere sfera1(0, 0, 0, 1);
Sphere sfera2(5, 0, 0, 1);


void myinit(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); // activare iluminare
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);    // activare sursa 0

    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void CALLBACK display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    sfera1.draw();
    sfera2.draw();
    glFlush();
}

void CALLBACK myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    if (!h) return;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(65.0, (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 1.0, 20.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotated(25, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, -1.0, -6.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auxInitDisplayMode(AUX_SINGLE | AUX_RGB | AUX_DEPTH16);
    auxInitPosition(0, 0, 850, 850);
    auxInitWindow("Iluminarea");
    myinit();
    glutSpecialFunc(sfera1.keyboardown);
    auxReshapeFunc(myReshape);
    auxMainLoop(display);
    return(0);
}
```

Sphere class:

```
#include "glos.h"
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>  
class Sphere{

public:
    float x, y, z, r;
    bool testColision = false;
    Sphere(float x, float y, float z, float r){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
        this->r = r;
    }
    bool colision(Sphere sfera){
        float d = sqrt(pow(++x - ++sfera.x, 2) + pow(++y - ++sfera.y, 2) + pow(++z - ++sfera.z, 2));
        if (d <= r + sfera.r){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    void draw(){
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        glutSolidSphere(r, 100, 100);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    void keyboardown(int key, int x, int y) {
        if (key == 'w')
            this->x += x;
        if (key == 'a')
            this->x -= x;
        if (key == 'd')
            this->y += y;
        if (key == 's')
            this->y -= y;

        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
};
```

I try to move it with glutSpecialFunc(sfera1.keyboardown) or with auxKeyFunc(AUX_RIGHT, sphere1.MutaDreapta1) but in both case I cant... can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Are glut and aux really supposed to be inter-operable ?
or was glutSpecialFunc a typo for auxSpecialFunc ? ;-)

anyway it's often better to use (glut)KeyboardFunc (on some systems, Up/Down/Special are doing bizarre things).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: A few minutes ago I didnot have the privilege to comment ;-).

Comment: ... anyway why my answer "don't mix aux and glut" isn't a valid answer ?

Comment: "_Are glut and aux really supposed to be inter-operable?_" looks more like a question.  "_Don't mix aux and glut_" would have been a better answer, if that's what you'd written.  You should edit your answer so it's more obviously providing a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: No: I never tried mixing glut and aux, so I won't allow myself to assert "it is wrong to", even if 99% certain. The appropriate way is thus to point out that excepted if I'm wrong and the guy know what he is doing, then it might be that problem is xxx. Just think about all the negative votes you got here from people understanding things less than you, or being ayatollah of some coding style :-( . It makes me recommanding more modest and positive behavior. I guess anyone can recognise answers, even is under-affirmative.